# Can Foundation 4 have a scope?

Tags: zurb-foundation

Can Foundation 4 be initialized only in certain areas of the page?

For instance, if I have 2 divs, can I call foundation("#div2") and all CSS and javascript events are applied only within div#2?

Thanks a 1000!

Comment: Are you just concerned about the grid system?

Comment: Hi no, mainly about the Javascript components. The CSS is easily fixed by recompiling SASS, but I don't know if they provide anything like that for JS, couldn't find in the docs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it won't affect you. The grid system for example is mainly controlled by CSS. For forms, unless you apply the `custom` class to your form the js for forms elements won't kick in. To illustrate that, one of the two forms below has the `custom` class and the other don't. Notice that Foundation will add two anchor tags and an unordered list for the form with `custom` class:

```
<form id="form1">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</form>
<form id="form2" class="custom">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDUxV/) to that to see it in action.

UPDATE: For general "section formatting" yes you can apply foundation to some sections of your page. But take note though that the grid system will still be applied even if the grid is outside the section you targeted. Again, that is because they are mainly controlled by CSS. Here's another illustration:

```
<h1>The Grid System will still be applied to this</h1>    
<div class="row1">
    <div class="large-5 large-centered columns">
        <p class="panel">Centered Div</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="foundationArea">
<h1>Only apply Foundation here</h1>
        <form id="form1" class="custom">
            <select>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns panel">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<h1>Foundation is not allowed here</h1>
<form id="form2" class="custom">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

[See this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDUxV/2/) to show the updated example given here.

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle and answer, von v. Basically, though, I'd like to find out if I can do this:
$('#sidebar').foundation(), and Foundation would only work inside #sidebar.

Comment: Actually, I edited the fiddle (first time I used it :-p), and it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/fDUxV/1/ I wonder why I couldn't find this feature in the documentation... Well, thanks! I'll keep experimenting.

Comment: You're welcome. See my updated answer and the updated fiddle that goes with it to further illustrate what you need.

Comment: Thanks a 1000! Looks like everything works as I had expected. Foundation is awesome. :-)

Comment: Yes it is. We have used it since v2 and they have matured quite well since then. Glad I was able to help :)